# Android - playing swf in background service is possible? if so,only with Webview?

Tags: android, flash, webview

So.. part of custom radio player app, some of the radio station stream type is flash.
Most of stations are 'normal' types which I can play with native mediaplayer on service but I'm not sure how to make it work with the swf links.
Create WebView that will open them in background - form service is possible? if so, that's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: _"some of the radio station stream type is flash"_ do you mean FLV format? If yes... could you not just extract the AAC audio's bytes out of the FLV container and just feed them to the Android decoder. I code AS3 (Flash) so can't show example code but I know Android can read bytes & bytes can be fed to the decoder for playback...

Comment: PS: An **swf** file is just a compiled app (like **apk** file). It's code must be getting the audio link (mp3 or aac) from somewhere else, usually the source code of the html page (that has swf embed code). Check it and copy audio link.

Comment: not sure how to take it's source as the parameters are part of an general object which is'nt proper URL which refer to audio link..
See this URL:
http://radio.coolsite.co.il/radio.php?radio=1

Inspecting this iframe we can see object with id:StrobeMediaPlayback
how can I translate this to an audio link?